# Android receivers - Same name and action of receiver in multiple apps

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

Let's say I have the following receiver in the manifest of 2 app (App A & App B):

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.COMMON_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In each app I want to create a `PendingIntent`, if not exists, and set it with inexact repeating using the `AlarmManager`. To check if one exists, I execute the following code:

```
boolean alarmExists = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            DEFAULT_PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Does this should return false in App A, even if App B already created the pending intent on the same device? **Is there a reason to defer the receivers in both apps** (by using different action for each of them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each application has its own `PendingIntent`s. These are not shared among different applications.

If application A has created a `PendingIntent` with ACTION="com.COMMON_ACTION", and application B does:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.COMMON_ACTION");
boolean alarmExists = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
        DEFAULT_PENDING_INTENT_ID, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

`alarmExists` will be `false`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me out to some docs? So basically, the intent filter checks also the creator package name?

Comment: Yes, it does. Unfortunately, this isn't clearly indicated in the documentation. You learn this stuff by testing it yourself and reading reams of source code ;-) It would take you 20 minutes to write a small test program to test this yourself.